# How to set up mongodb in node.js/visual studios

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, mongodb

Hi guys ive been trying to set up my database for days! im using node.js and the visual studios plug in for it. Im trying to set up my database and see if it works. Ive installed mongodb and mongoose but i dont know how to set the database up. Would really appreciate some help

Comment: Setting up MongoDB is not connected with visual studio at all. What problem do you have?

Comment: when i go to the folder where i have my mongodb downloaded in the command prompt and when i type mongo to see if its running i get the error mongo is not recognised as internal or external comand

Comment: Em, what? May be you should google for a tutorial on how to install Mongo on Windows?

Comment: ya found a tutorial on youtube :D man im retarded....